# MySQL: store rare long string

Tags: mysql

There is a MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `variables` (
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

There is only one type of SELECT: select one row by the key.

`value` is usually short (in most cases less than 10 characters).
But under new conditions it is in very rare cases (<1%) it can be long (about 10 Kb).
How should I change the table?

As I understand `VARCHAR(15000)` is more efficient in this case than `TEXT`.
But what about this solution?

```sql
CREATE TABLE `variables` (
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    `long_value` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

If the value is short then save it to the `value`.
A long value save to `long_value`.

After `SELECT value,long_value FROM variables WHERE name=?` check which column is not NULL.
Or just `SELECT IFNULL(value, long_value) AS value WHERE variables WHERE name=?`.

Comment: What do you understand by 'more efficient'?

Comment: *There is only one type of SELECT: select one row by the key.* I think that the root of the unefficiency is `VARCHAR(50)` column which is used as primary key and searching criteria.

Comment: Use TEXT for `value` and drop the `long_value` column. MySQL is already doing well, what you try to do. The overhead of TEXT is 2 bytes. The overhead of `VARCHAR(250)` (with utf8mb4) is also 2 bytes. The way the values are stored is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the VARCHAR(15000) for the data. The space taken in the DB is the actual data length + few bytes of overhead. This will work for both the short and long strings.

Separating the data into two fields just creates additional complexity in your application and actually wastes space.